# CSS style loaded first content while internet slow connection

Tags: css

When I open my web page on a slow internet connection it shows css style(border, ...) first content that load from database.

Why it become like this? Any solutions to solve this?

Comment: it could be because of css file is already cached in your browser. 
try in another browser/incognito mode or clear browser cache

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour.  Once you have first visited a page, the CSS file will be cached on your PC and will not need to re-download - hence it appearing to download first on subsequent pages.  To get around this, you would need to turn caching off on your web browser - although this would not be a smart move since you have a slow connection.

Hope this helps.